# new data list and functions with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Good evening I have a dataset containing data on football matches like this:

```
   Date       HomeTeam   AwayTeam   RESULT  
   <date>     <fct>      <fct>      <fct>  
 1 2018-08-18 Milan      Juventus   A     
 2 2018-08-18 Roma       Napoli     Draw     
 3 2018-08-19 Bologna    Inter      A      
 4 2018-08-25 Juventus   Roma       Draw    
 5 2018-08-25 Napoli     Bologna    H      
 6 2018-08-26 Inter      Milan      H
```

I was wondering if it was possible to list the different teams and associate the round number with the day. it is also possible to know how many matches a team does not draw?

```
   Date       Teams      ROUND  RoundNoDraw
   <date>     <fct>      <int>  <int>  
 1 2018-08-18 Milan      1      1
 2 2018-08-18 Juventus   1      1
 3 2018-08-18 Roma       1      0
 4 2018-08-18 Napoli     1      0
 5 2018-08-19 Bologna    1      1
 6 2018-08-19 Inter      1      1
 7 2018-08-25 Juventus   2      0
 8 2018-08-25 Roma       2      0
 9 2018-08-25 Napoli     2      1
10 2018-08-25 Bologna    2      1
11 2018-08-26 Inter      2      2
12 2018-08-26 Milan      2      2
```

I would like to do all through the dplyr package, I apologize for my English, thanks for your attention

Comment: How do you know when a `ROUND` changes ?

Comment: Also, can you clarify `RoundNoDraw`? Is this cumulative (Milan and Inter have 2 non-draws after two games, but so does Bologna)?

Comment: No response to questions asking for clarification of rules for "ROUND". Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: It would be one match (per team) per round. There are ten matches in total per round (Serie A is a 20 team competition).

Comment: A round is an integer variable that starts at 0 and increments by 1 when the team plays again. 
I was wrong for Bologna on line 10 2018-08-25 Bologna 2 1 it should be 10 2018-08-25 Bologna 2 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse` and `lubridate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat <- read.table(text = "   Date       HomeTeam   AwayTeam   RESULT  
 1 '2018-08-18' Milan      Juventus   A     
 2 '2018-08-18' Roma       Napoli     Draw     
 3 '2018-08-19' Bologna    Inter      A      
 4 '2018-08-25' Juventus   Roma       Draw    
 5 '2018-08-25' Napoli     Bologna    H      
 6 '2018-08-26' Inter      Milan      H  ",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(RoundNoDraw = as.integer(RESULT != "Draw")) %>%
  gather(HomeAway, Teams, ends_with("Team")) %>%
  mutate(ROUND = dense_rank(week(Date))) %>%
  arrange(ROUND, Date) %>%
  group_by(Teams) %>%
  mutate(RoundNoDraw = cumsum(RoundNoDraw)) %>%
  select(Date, Teams, ROUND, RoundNoDraw) %>%
  ungroup()

dat2
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#    Date       Teams    ROUND RoundNoDraw
#    <chr>      <chr>    <int>       <int>
#  1 2018-08-18 Milan        1           1
#  2 2018-08-18 Roma         1           0
#  3 2018-08-18 Juventus     1           1
#  4 2018-08-18 Napoli       1           0
#  5 2018-08-19 Bologna      1           1
#  6 2018-08-19 Inter        1           1
#  7 2018-08-25 Juventus     2           1
#  8 2018-08-25 Napoli       2           1
#  9 2018-08-25 Roma         2           0
# 10 2018-08-25 Bologna      2           2
# 11 2018-08-26 Inter        2           2
# 12 2018-08-26 Milan        2           2
```

Comment: I just realised that `RoundNoDraw` for `Bologna` is not correct as `Bologna` lost to Inter in the first round. That's why I deleted my answer:)

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan OP mentioned nothing about distinguishing win or lose, just draw. So I think your answer is fine.

Comment: www you're right I made a mistake. Thanks for your help, you were great

Comment: @www How should I do to reset the RoundNoDraw variable count to zero every time there is a Draw?

Comment: @PabloPicciau Not sure what do you mean reset. Perhaps post a new question.